# Error Biztalk A message received by adapter "SOAP" on receive location "Invoice Receive Location" with URI is suspended

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

Can anyone help with this error?

> A message received by adapter "SOAP" on receive location "Invoice Receive Location" with URI "/B2BOrchestrations_WebService/B2BOrchestrations_B2BProcess_ReceiveInvoice_Port.asmx" is suspended.

Answer (score 2):

It means BizTalk has been unable to process the message and so has placed it into a suspended state. If you open the BizTalk administration console then click the 'group hub' followed by refresh you should see a link to suspended items. From here you should be able to find your suspended message along with an error message explaining why it was suspended.

One common reason for suspension is that there were no active subscribers for the message. Is it possible that a send port that should be posting the received message has been unenlisted?